# The order of values in ? : expression

Tags: java, programming-practices

Which construction is more readable:

1. ```
   someVariable == null ? SOME_VALUE : someVariable; // avoids negation
   ```
2. ```
   someVariable != null ? someVariable : SOME_VALUE; // normal situation first
   ```

I have to use such expressions very often, but I was never really sure which one is better.

Comment: In what language?  In C or C++, it's idiomatic to omit the explicit comparison with null, and write `someVariable ? someVariable : SOME_VALUE`.  And I think C# has a `??` operator as a short-circuit "first non-null" operator.

Comment: I was thinking about Java.

Comment: I've added the Java tag for you (pending review).  :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, when it comes to conditionals, it is usually easier to read a *positive* clause than a negative one.

So `someVariable == null` would be better than `someVariable != null` - for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Also some programmers said that there is a good reason to use`null` first:

`if(null == someVariable)`

Using null first uses a default equality comparator. :-?

Comment: I always thought the reason for doing it that way was to guard against errors such as `if(someVariable = null)`?